# Text to bigint conversion in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2017

I am trying to convert a number which is taken from an Excel file stored as text but shows 9.2342431106e+11 and I need to convert it to `bigint`

Comment: Your best bet is to use SQL Server's import wizard, and read a CSV exported from Excel.  This should (ideally) take care of this problem automatically.

Comment: `select  replace(cast(cast(cast('9.2342431106e+11' as real) as money) as nvarchar(255)),'.00','')` taken from here (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9753eadd-5677-4ed9-8942-b3528785253b/convert-from-scientific-notation?forum=transactsql)

Comment: after trying this number was changed